# How to get IPaddess from given String

Tags: c#, wpf

I have String like this:

> http://192.168.xx.xx/abc/abcd.php

and want to fetch only ipaddress from it.
The Expected output should be:

> 192.168.xx.xx

I can do this by splitting it by '/' but is there any easy way out.

Comment: Use a Uri parsing function

Comment: Alternative would be `Regex`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, give this a try:

```
var url = "http://192.168.1.1/abc/abcd.php";
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
var ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(uri.Host)[0];
Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString());
```

You will need `System.Net` for this.